# Using earlier version of mathematica

Tags: installation

I have installed Mathematica v.9 previously, but I am tempted to use of Mathematica V.10, for this aim, before acting to Install newer version, do I have to **uninstall** V.9 completely. Or not (an option has embedded to V.10 for just upgrading and promotion of older version?) (I mean v.9 does not need to be uninstalled)? (I have heard, although I am not sure it is correct or not, just I heard, if I uninstall an older version in a machine I will face to many problems in order to use of any version of Mathematica again)

Comment: One of the related questions: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28186/can-mathematica-9-peacefully-coexist-with-mathematica-8-on-windows

Comment: I have v9 and all versions since 10.0.0 installed on my Mac. They happily coexist. I can even run these different versions at the same time. I believe this is even documented to be a supported case; I just don't remember where.

Comment: Related: "[Setting default Mathematica version](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14991/280)."

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using a Windows machine. I have used Mathematica since version 7 and the upgrades are smooth. You do not have to be concerned about uninstall since the installation package will move the older files for you.

Comment: Yes I am using of win 7